# Make the first cell automatically selected when VC opens is not working

Tags: swift

I have a ViewController that have a collectionView and I managed to make it selectable and all but the problem is that I have a checkmark image that stays in the first cell when the VC opens but in fact the cell is not selected at all and still the checkmark is there!

Code of the VC:

```
  var selected = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)

  var properties =  connectedProperties(StatusCode: 0)
  var propertiesNew =  connectedProperties(StatusCode: 0)


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return properties.Result?.count ?? 0
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dashboardCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? dashboardCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
    
    let currentPropertie = properties.Result?[indexPath.row]
            
    cell.checkMarkButton.isHidden = !(indexPath == selected)
        
    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = properties.Result?[indexPath.row]
    
    changeCustomerKey.DefaultsKeys.keyTwo = indexPath.row
    changeCustomerKey.DefaultsKeys.keyThree = selectedCell!.id!
    
    let previous = selected.dropLast()
    selected = indexPath
    
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [previous, selected])
}
```

Comment: Unclear what the goal is. Do you want the check mark image to be visible or not?

Comment: @matt I want the checkmark to be visible only when the cell is selected, But in my case the checkmark is still there even though the cell is not selected sir

Comment: It _is_ "selected". You yourself set `var selected = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)`, and this cell _is_  at `IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)`.

Comment: @matt Aww how didn't I notice that, thats actually correct but how can i automatically select the cell when the view opens "the first cell", and thanks a lot for the clarification!

Comment: To be clear: You want your view controller to select the first cell once it is done populating cells. Further, the behavior you expect is for the selected cell to show a check-mark. Is that correct?

Comment: @DuncanC Yes Duncan excactly!

Comment: I don't know what "opens" a cell even means. Your code is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: @matt By opens i mean when the cell are populated as Duncan said, Because when the cells are populated the checkmark is in the first cell but in the backround that cell is not selected at all when the cells are populated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tell your collection view to select a specific cell, you need to call the UICollectionView method `selectItem(at:animated:scrollPosition:)`.

The "tricky bit" is that you can't call that until the collection view has finished populating itself (by calling your data source methods) and the first cell has been added to the collection view.

You might need to resort to something a bit hacky like adding an "initialDisplay" bool property who's value starts as true.

In your data source method that returns cells, check if `initialDisplay==true` and the requested indexPath is (0,0). If so, set `initialDisplay=false`, and fire a one-shot timer with a short delay. In the timer's closure, call `selectItem(at:animated:scrollPosition:)`. The timer delay will return control to the event loop and give the system time to add the cell to the collection view.

There might be a better way to do this, but I can't think of it offhand, since you can't be sure when you will be asked to return your cell at IndexPath `(0,0)`